# PostgreSql Update function on multiple databases

Tags: database, postgresql

For my application, we are creating the Databases programatically thru code from c#. We create separate postgresql databases for every user as he signs up for the application.

The postgreSQL functions get created on their own when we create the database because I have stored them in the template DB.

However, when the function has to be updated, i have to manually go and update the function in every database for each user.

I am unable to think of a way, that the functions can be centrally stored somewhere so that I can just update them at single place, and every database can reference them from single place without storing the copy of functions at each database.

Or My code can detect that somehow the function has changed, and it needs to be updated on the server.

Comment: "*We create separate postgresql databases for every user*" - that sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: "We create separate postgresql databases for every user"  - I think heroku does it

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is not to use different databases, but different database schemas within one database.

That way you can have a function in one schema (typically `public`) and use that for all users.